# How to change \autocites delimiter (semicolon) when empty page specifier in postnote?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, punctuation

I've been trying to solve the following problem.

Consider this example line.
I presume the existence of some given document `main.tex` and some `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass[14pt, project, twoside]{extreport}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=biber,citepages=omit]{biblatex}
\bibliography{some-bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Text in the document.\autocites[See][]{author1_title1_date1}[See][\nopp page reference]{author2_title2_date2}

\end{document}
```

Note that the postnote of the first citation is empty.
This compiles to the following:

[image: Semicolon where full stop is desired.]

Can I exceptionally change this semicolon separating the postnote of the first citation to a full stop instead?
I do not want this to be a general rule, but I would like more flexibility as to how I begin the prenote to the next citation.

Comment: With `\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addperiod\space}}` you could affect the entire citation. That would mean that if you cited three works all of them would be separated with a period. If you really only want the influence the first citekey, something more devious is needed.

Comment: BTW: While your question is quite general and can be understood without an example, it could be that custom styles handle certain things like `\multicitedelim` a bit different. So if you want to be sure that our solutions are tested with your setup, a short example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows which style you use and any other relevant modifications could be useful nonetheless.

Comment: Hi moewe, thanks for your answer, it works perfectly! I was surprised that such a workaround is required for such a simple request, but I'm most happy with the result. I also followed up on your advice and provided a minimal working example. Cheers!

Comment: Given that `\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addperiod\space}` would be the code to change the delimiter globally for all citations and additional `\AtNextCite` does not seem to be so complicated. Not everything can be done with a single option. And it seems to me that changing the delimiter between different citation calls is one of the more unusual things one could ask for.

Comment: Especially if you want to be flexible you need to have a way to tell `biblatex` that you want to have this case handled differently, so it is not too surprising that a certain amount of work is needed.

Comment: Point taken, really! I just find that in longer footnotes —with a lot of surrounding pre- and postnotes— semicolons tend to be tiresome to the eye. I'm happy with this.

Comment: Oh, I don't disagree that periods probably look better at some point. I just get a bit overprotective sometimes when people say things should be easier ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With

```
\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addperiod\space}}
```

you can temporarily change the delimiter between multiple citations for the next `\...cite` evocation. That will affect the entire `\...cite` call, though. If you need a more fine grained control, for example to change only the first delimiter, more complicated tricks are needed.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=biber,citepages=omit]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Text in the document.\autocites[See][]{sigfridsson}[See][page reference]{worman}

\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addperiod\space}}
Text in the document.\autocites[See][]{sigfridsson}[See][page reference]{worman}

Text in the document.\autocites[See][]{sigfridsson}[See][page reference]{worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: See Sigfridsson and Ryde, ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. See Worman, Cast of Character, page reference.//See Sigfridsson and Ryde, ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’; See Worman, Cast of Character, page reference.]